# May I reuse my previous deactivated blog post (article) on my new site?

Tags: seo, google, post, articles

2–3 months has passed since my domain and hosting expired on my old site. There were almost 10 posts on my previous (expired) blog.

May I reuse my old post/article on my new site? Is there any issue with Google or SEO in general if I reuse my old post.

Comment: Sorry but you have failed to mention what your concern is?, is it duplicate content? if so, as soon Google has dropped the content.

Comment: My concern is, If i use the content in my new site then there is any possibility to count the content as a duplicate. However, my previous site has no existence over the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @closetnoc method if your old article is no longer indexed by google.
But if its sitll exist on google search, make sure you redirect your old article from `Gogle Webmaster Tools` to your new site.

Answer (score 0):

Once your old blog no longer shows up in the Google SERPs, then you can add your article to the new blog.

*That is the technically correct answer.*

*Now for my answer.*

If your blog is dead and will not show up again and you are sure of that, there is no problem adding your article now. **One duplicate page will not harm you** especially when the old one is gone. By the time Google figures it out, the problem will have corrected itself anyhow.